# Badge earned in user profile - "Let us pick" button in mobile browser in misleading context

Tags: bug, profile-page

I earned a badge recently, and noticed that there was a <kbd>Let us pick</kbd> button next to the badge. I interpreted the information on the page as if it's trying to tell me *here's the badge you're meant to get, or you can let us choose a different one for you*.

When visiting the main site it becomes clear what this button is referring to - `Track the next one`, but that text seems to have disappeared in the mobile view.

See screenshot below.

It would be nice if this could be fixed. I think the <kbd>Let us pick</kbd> button should only show up if the accompanying `Track the next one` is there, too.

[image]

Comment: I don't see *"here's the badge you're meant to get, or you can let us choose a different one for you"* when I look at it, instead, I see *"Let us pick another badge."*. But whatever anyone sees, it should **definitely** be changed from *"Let us pick"* to *"Let us pick your next badge"*.

Comment: The "here's the badge you're meant to get, or you can let us choose a different one for you" was my interpretation of what I saw on the screen the first time round, not a quote - sorry. I'll change the formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: No, I understood that. I was quoting **you**. By "see" I meant "see the meaning of". Sorry if ***I*** was unclear, *you* certainly weren't!

Comment: ah right, now I understand. Now your first statement makes sense, thanks!